# automatic update of date when inserting new row

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that will update a column date by one month whenever a new row is added.

This is what I have, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tg_nextupdate
BEFORE INSERT
ON Vehicle
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.NextUpdate = SYSDATE
    THEN
    SET NextUpdate = ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,1);
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: There is no need of `IF-END IF` block. Simply, `:NEW.NextUpdate = ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,1); `

Comment: Is `NextUpdate` always 1 month after `SYSDATE`, or is there some additional requirement/special cases ? What is `NextUpdate`  was set in the `INSERT` query ? Do you need to override it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of `IF-END IF` block, whenever a new row is inserted, it will have sysdate. So, just update the `NextUpdate` to `ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,1)` directly. The check on `IF :NEW.NextUpdate = SYSDATE` is not required.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tg_nextupdate
BEFORE INSERT
ON Vehicle
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   :NEW.NextUpdate = ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,1);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encounter a problem with your code when NextUpdate contains only date, without of hours, minutes and seconds.
Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tg_nextupdate
BEFORE INSERT
ON Vehicle
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.NextUpdate = trunc(SYSDATE)
    THEN
    SET NextUpdate = ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,1);
    END IF;
END;
```

Or give us more details about what you want and what you get with your code.

Comment: There is no need of `IF-END IF`. If a row is inserted, just update the column to next month date, what's the need to check for sysdate?

Comment: As I can see, he wants to add one month only if NextUpdate is equal to current date. In this case he need IF - END IF.

Comment: If a new row is inserted, what is the need to check for NextUpdate? It is the same column that needs to be update to a month later date.

Comment: It is a question for user2409, not for me.

Answer (score 0):

> This is what I have, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Assuming `NextUpdate` having for default value `SYSDATE`, as it has already been say, you `IF` is maybe "not necessary"...

... *but*, as of myself, I think the real issue is `SYSDATE` not guaranteeing to return the *same value* upon each call. If you don't believe me, try that http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f810/2

So, your column might very well be properly initialized by `SYSDATE` to, say "October, 26 2014 18:50:10+0000". But, in your trigger, `SYSDATE` might very well return "October, 26 2014 18:50:11+0000". This would be bad luck, I admit. And maybe this is acceptable in your application. But in a more general case, this might easily become a hard to track bug.

Depending your needs, I would suggest one of those three options instead:

1) Assuming `SYSDATE` is a "magical value" meaning "hey trigger! Compute the right value for `NextUpdate`":

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tg_nextupdate
BEFORE INSERT
ON Vehicle
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.NextUpdate <= SYSDATE
    THEN
        :NEW.NextUpdate := SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' MONTH;
    END IF;
END;
```

So, any time in the past will trigger the calculation of a new `NextUpdate`. Including 1s in the past.

2) Override `NextUpdate` from the trigger -- always:

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicle (value NUMBER(10),
                NextUpdate DATE)
--              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
--          No need for default here
--          as we override values
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tg_nextupdate
BEFORE INSERT
ON Vehicle
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    :NEW.NextUpdate := SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' MONTH;
END;
/

INSERT INTO Vehicle(value) VALUES (1)
/
INSERT INTO Vehicle VALUES (2, TO_DATE('30/10/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'))
/
INSERT INTO Vehicle VALUES (3, TO_DATE('30/12/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'))
/
INSERT INTO Vehicle VALUES (4, NULL)
/
```

3) Set `NextUpdate` defaults to SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' MONTH, allow the user to change that when inserting. *If you need it*, a trigger might keep the `LEAST` value (+/- the 1 second error as explained in preamble):

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicle (value NUMBER(10),
                NextUpdate DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' MONTH)
--              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
--                   set default to the "most probable" value
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tg_nextupdate
BEFORE INSERT
ON Vehicle
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    LimitNextUpdate DATE := SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' MONTH;
BEGIN
    :NEW.NextUpdate := LEAST(LimitNextUpdate, 
                             NVL(:NEW.NextUpdate,LimitNextUpdate));
    --                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    --                      required if the used set the value to NULL
END;
/

INSERT INTO Vehicle(value) VALUES (1)
/
INSERT INTO Vehicle VALUES (2, TO_DATE('30/10/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'))
/
INSERT INTO Vehicle VALUES (3, TO_DATE('30/12/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'))
/
INSERT INTO Vehicle VALUES (4, NULL)
/
```

You will need to add extra logic (either in the trigger or as a check constraint) in order to reject `NextUpdate` in the past.